# How to make threads in Java run concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrent-programming

I'm trying out this code and I'm a bit confused/surprised at the output I'm getting. I'm still new to Java but I'm aware that threads should normally run concurrently. It seems my "printB" thread here waits for the "printA" thread before it starts executing. I've run the program several times (hoping to get a mixture of both threads' outcome i.e. something like: a, a, b, a, b, a...) but still I get the same output (i.e. "A" getting printed first, before "B"). Why is this happening and how can I alter the code to start behaving normally?

Any inputs/suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Also, I'm trying out the same code using the extends Thread method and it doesn't work.

```
class PrintChars implements Runnable{
    private char charToPrint;
    private int times;

    public PrintChars(char c, int t){
        charToPrint = c;
        times = t;        
    }


    public void run(){
        for (int i=0; i<times; i++)
        System.out.println(charToPrint);        
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

        PrintChars charA = new PrintChars('a', 7);
        PrintChars charB = new PrintChars('b', 5);

        Thread printA = new Thread(charA);
        Thread printB = new Thread(charB);

        printA.start();
        printB.start();
    }
}
```

Extends Thread method below:

```
class PrintChars extends Thread {

private Char charToPrint;
private int times;


public PrintChars(char c, int t){
    charToPrint = c;
    times = t;
}


public void run (){

    for(int i =0; i<times; i++)
            System.out.println(charToPrint);
    }

    PrintChars printA = new PrintChars('a', 7);
    PrintChars printB = new PrintChars('a', 5);

    printA.start();
    printB.start();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In multithreading, usually you can't make *any* assumption about the output.

Perhaps the time used to create the thread is very long, hence the previous thread has time to complete entirely, since its execution is very short.

Try with 7000 and 5000 instead of 7 and 5.

Answer (score 4):

Each thread takes time to start and can run to completion very quickly.  I suggest you add `Thread.sleep(500);` after each line printed.

```
try {
    for(int i =0; i<times; i++) {
        System.out.println(charToPrint);
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
} catch(InterruptedException ie) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thread scheduling is not deterministic. It's perfectly fine for the OS to schedule one thread, and only schedule the second after the first has completed.

If you think about it from the OS' point of view, it makes sense.. If somebody asked you to do two tasks, it may be more efficient to do one and then the other.

When the task takes too long to execute, as an OS you'll probably want to task switch and do something on the other task as otherwise the other task won't progress at all, and the app. that issued the task will feel discriminated.

You can see this by making your task run longer, e.g. by adding `Thread.sleep` statements or calculating PI or something (or just loop for more than 7, like 70000).

Answer (score 2):

I think the execution times for your threads are too short to notice an effect. You can try higher values for `times`. I would try something `>10000`. Another option is to increase the execution time by making the method slower:

```
public void run(){
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      System.out.println(charToPrint); 
      try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running it a few more times. When I tried it with 700/500 I noticed some interweaving.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is behaving normally only, if your expectation is to have mixture of a and b's printed, then you should sufficiently print chars not just couple of times, or use Thread.sleep() or do a busy wait running a for loop doing nothing for a million times.